# How to reuse class from another file

Tags: python

I import `technicals.py` into `bot.py` and want to reuse the variable `sl` and `tp` from the class instance `process_candles`.

If a constant number is given to `sl` and `tp` in `bot.py`, the script is able to work. However, the desired result is to get variable `sl` and `tp` which is calculated in the class instance `process_candles`. from `technicals.py`.

snippet `technicals.py` as below:

```
    df['PAIR'] = self.pair
    decision = NONE
    tp = 0
    sl = 0
if c[-2]>o[-2]:
    if ca[-1]>h[-2]+0.0010:
        decision = BUY
        tp = ca[-1]+0.010
        sl = l[-2]-0.010 
elif o[-2]>c[-2]:
    if cb[-1]<l[-2]-0.0010:
        decision = SELL 
        tp = cb[-1]-0.010
        sl = h[-2]+0.010                
else:
    decision = NONE
```

snippet `bot.py`

```
 def process_pairs(self):      
        trades_to_make = []
        for pair in self.trade_pairs:
            if self.timings[pair].ready == True:
                self.log_message(f"Ready to trade {pair}") 
                techs = Technicals(self.settings[pair], self.api, pair, GRANULARITY, log=self.tech_log)
                decision = techs.get_trade_decision(self.timings[pair].last_candle)
                print ("process decision")
                print (decision)
                units = decision * self.settings[pair].units


                #tp = "154"
                #sl = "153"

                if units != 0:
                    trades_to_make.append({'pair': pair, 'units': units,'take_profit':tp, 'stop_loss':sl})
```

Full script are as below:

**technicals.py**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from defs import BUY, SELL, NONE

class Technicals():
    
    def __init__(self, settings, api, pair, granularity, log=None):
        self.settings = settings
        self.log = log
        self.api = api
        self.pair = pair
        self.granularity = granularity
    
    def log_message(self, msg):
        if self.log is not None:
            self.log.logger.debug(msg)

    
    def fetch_candles(self, row_count, candle_time):
        status_code, df = self.api.fetch_candles(self.pair, count=row_count, granularity=self.granularity)
        if df is None:
            self.log_message(f"Error fetching candles for pair:{self.pair} {candle_time}, df None")
            return None
        elif df.iloc[-1].time != candle_time:
            self.log_message(f"Error fetching candles for pair:{self.pair} {candle_time} vs {df.iloc[-1].time}")
            return None
        else:
            return df

    
    def process_candles(self, df):
        open = df.mid_o
        o = np.array(open,dtype='float') 
        #print (o)
                
        high = df.mid_h
        h = np.array(high,dtype='float') 
        #print (h)

        low = df.mid_l
        l = np.array(low,dtype='float')
        #print (l)

        close = df.mid_c
        c = np.array(close,dtype='float')
        print (c)

        close_ask = df.ask_c
        ca = np.array(close_ask,dtype='float')
        print (ca)

        close_bid = df.bid_c
        cb = np.array(close_bid,dtype='float')
        print (cb)

        df['PAIR'] = self.pair
        decision = NONE
        tp = 0
        sl = 0
    if c[-2]>o[-2]:
        if ca[-1]>h[-2]+0.0010:
            decision = BUY
            tp = ca[-1]+0.010
            sl = l[-2]-0.010 
    elif o[-2]>c[-2]:
        if cb[-1]<l[-2]-0.0010:
            decision = SELL 
            tp = cb[-1]-0.010
            sl = h[-2]+0.010                
    else:
        decision = NONE        

    log_cols = ['time','volume','PAIR','bid_c','ask_c','mid_o','mid_h','mid_l','mid_c']
    self.log_message(f"Processed_df\n{df[log_cols].tail(3)}")
    self.log_message(f"Trade_decision:{decision}")
    self.log_message("")

    return decision


def get_trade_decision(self, candle_time):

    max_rows = self.settings.long_ma + 2
    self.log_message("")
    self.log_message(f"get_trade_decision() pair:{self.pair} max_rows:{max_rows}")

    df = self.fetch_candles(max_rows, candle_time)
    print ("xxxx")
    print (df)
    if df is not None:
        return self.process_candles(df)
    print("get trade decision")
    print(self.process_candles(df))

    return NONE
```

**bot.py**

```
import pprint
import time

from settings import Settings
from log_wrapper import LogWrapper
from timing import Timing
from oanda_api import OandaAPI
from technicals import Technicals
from defs import NONE, BUY, SELL
from trade_manager import TradeManager

GRANULARITY = "M1"
SLEEP = 10.0

class TradingBot():
    
    def __init__(self):    
        self.log = LogWrapper("Bot")
        self.tech_log = LogWrapper("Technicals")
        self.trade_log = LogWrapper("Trade")
        self.trade_pairs = Settings.get_pairs()
        self.settings = Settings.load_settings()
        self.api = OandaAPI()
        self.trade_manager = TradeManager(self.api, self.settings, self.trade_log)
        self.timings = { p: Timing(self.api.last_complete_candle(p, GRANULARITY)) for p in self.trade_pairs }
        self.log_message(f"Bot started with\n{pprint.pformat(self.settings)}")
        self.log_message(f"Bot Timings\n{pprint.pformat(self.timings)}")
        print (self.api)
        
    def log_message(self, msg):
        self.log.logger.debug(msg)       
    
    def update_timings(self):        
        for pair in self.trade_pairs:
            current = self.api.last_complete_candle(pair, GRANULARITY)
            self.timings[pair].ready = False
            if current > self.timings[pair].last_candle:
                self.timings[pair].ready = True
                self.timings[pair].last_candle = current
                self.log_message(f"{pair} new candle {current}")

    def process_pairs(self):      
        trades_to_make = []
        for pair in self.trade_pairs:
            if self.timings[pair].ready == True:
                self.log_message(f"Ready to trade {pair}") 
                techs = Technicals(self.settings[pair], self.api, pair, GRANULARITY, log=self.tech_log)
                decision = techs.get_trade_decision(self.timings[pair].last_candle)
                print ("process decision")
                print (decision)
                units = decision * self.settings[pair].units


                #tp = "154"
                #sl = "153"

                if units != 0:
                    trades_to_make.append({'pair': pair, 'units': units,'take_profit':tp, 'stop_loss':sl})

        if len(trades_to_make) > 0:
            print("bot")
            print(trades_to_make)
            self.trade_manager.place_trades(trades_to_make)
        
    
    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.update_timings()
            self.process_pairs()
            time.sleep(SLEEP)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = TradingBot()
    b.run()
```

**defs.py**

```
API_KEY = "xxxx"
ACCOUNT_ID = "xyz"
OANDA_URL = 'https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3'

SECURE_HEADER = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {API_KEY}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}


BUY = 1
SELL = -1
NONE = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just returning the decision, also return the take profit and stop loss values:

```
return decision, tp, sl
```

Then you can unpack the tuple in `process_pairs`:

```
decision, tp, sl = techs.get_trade_decision(self.timings[pair].last_candle)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your `tp` and `sl` as class variables of `Technicals`.

```py
class Technicals(object):
    tp: int = 0
    sl: int = 0
```

and use them within `Technicals` as:

```py
    cls.tp = ... # if you are inside class-method
    self.tp = ... # if you are inside instance-method
```

And in the `TradingBot` you can then simple import `Technicals` and use the class-Vars like:

```py
tp = Technicals.tp # you can use the class
tp = techs.tp # or the instance you already have
```